# How do I jump to next reference in Resharper?

Tags: c#, resharper, coderush

When I tried out CodeRush from DevExpress, there was this awesome feature called [Tab to next reference](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#CodeRush/CustomDocument3864).

Is there similar feature in Resharper? I'm using <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F12</kbd> to bring up "Uses of" context menu, which is good but slower to work with.

Edit: I asked because google search turned up nothing. Now this question is spot 5 for googling  Resharper jump to next reference.

Comment: I think this is a reasonable question about a well know tool used by thousands of developers. No reason to close as too localized or not a real question

Comment: agree, good question. For me - I didn't knew about fixing variable usages in R# and then navigating through it with selected one.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Down</kbd>(<kbd>Up</kbd>)    - IDEA Shortcut Scheme

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>PgDn</kbd>(<kbd>PgUp</kbd>)  - Visual Studio Scheme

Also bring short menu of all usages

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd>- IDEA Scheme

<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F12</kbd>- Visual Studio Scheme

Also

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd>

to highlight usages even if cursor has gone away. In screenshot I have fixed `_ninjectKernel` and put cursor to module variable. Navigation between usages of `_ninjectKernel` and `module` is done by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>PgUp</kbd>  (or <kbd>Up</kbd> for IDEA scheme )

[image]

Comment: :-( Unfortunately this only navigates between references in the same file where CodeRush's Tab will navigate through the references solution wide.

Comment: I loved CodeRush you could simply Tab to next occurrence.  I find it hard to believe this is not available in either Visual Studio or ReSharper.